# Changing font size in line number

Tags: line-numbering

I want to have the line number like this, but in a different color
[image: the one I expected but with different font color]

I used the following code:

```
    \usepackage{lineno}
    \linenumbers
```

When I am using the following code the problem is solved, but the font size is bigger:

```
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{lineno}
    \renewcommand{\linenumberfont}{\normalfont\bfseries\small\color{blue}}
    \linenumbers
```

[image: output received]

How can I change the font color but keep it the same size?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The default definition of `\linenumberfont` is `\normalfont\tiny\sffamily`.

Comment: When I replaced "small" with "tiny", it worked perfectly.